# Database query multiple parameters, multiple models

Tags: laravel, eloquent

In my project I have 4 models:

- Country
- City
- Hotel
- Room

So.. A `Country` has many `Cities`, a `City` has many `Hotels`, and so on..

Now, I want to display a page with rooms by accessing an url like:

`example.com/last-minute/{country}/{city}/{hotel}`

A page like `example.com/last-minute/us/nyc/hilton` should display all rooms within the `us`, within `nyc` and within the `hilton` hotel.

Now I need a database query to get the data that I want to display.

Something like this works:

```
$rooms = Room::where('hotel_slug', '=', $hotel)->get();
```

But this creates a problem when I als have a `Hilton` hotel in, for example, Amsterdam.

Comment: If you have relationships setup perhaps the `whereHas` method could be useful ... https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to create a local scope inside `Room` model.

Better to use `joins` instead of `whereHas` (it's very slow).

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Room extends Model
{
    public function scopeOnPlace($query, $country, $city, $hotel)
    {
        return $query->select('rooms.*')
            ->join('hotels', 'rooms.hotel_id', '=', 'hotels.id')
            ->join('cities', 'hotels.city_id', '=', 'cities.id')
            ->join('countries', 'cities.country_id', '=', 'countries.id')
            ->where('countries.slug', $country)
            ->where('cities.slug', $city)
            ->where('hotels.slug', $hotel);
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like:

```
$rooms = Room::onPlace($country, $city, $hotel)->get();
```

For example

```
Route::get('last-minute/{country}/{city}/{hotel}', [LastMinuteController::class, 'show']);
```

```
class LastMinuteController extends Controller
{
    public function show($country, $city, $hotel)
    {
        $rooms = Room::onPlace($country, $city, $hotel)->get();
    }
}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#local-scopes